# How to remap interrupt signal in zsh

Tags: zsh, remapping, signal

In bash I can remap Ctrl-C or interrupt signal to `Ctrl-J` by this line

```
stty intr ^J
```

In zsh it doesn't work neither `stty intr \^J`

How to remap interrupt signal to `Ctrl-J`?

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: In `zsh` on Ubuntu 18.04, `stty intr ^J` works fine. What does `stty -a` show for the interrupt character after you make this command?

Comment: It shows this `... intr = ^J; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; ...` Seems it already set up, but it doesn't work

Comment: I don't have a problem, but `Ctrl-J` is the new-line character, so some other input configuration may be affecting how `Ctrl-J` is handled. Have you tried a different control character to see if that works?

Comment: You're right, it does work with other character

Comment: The `eol` and `eol2` characters are undefined in my `stty -a`. If one of these is set to `^J` on your system, that might explain it. Otherwise, I don't know what else to suggest.